# How to upload code from vsCode to IP-restricted server

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, proxy, sftp, vpn

I have access to VPN, which allows me to connect (ssh) serverA behind firewall, and this serverA behind firewall have access to this IP restricted serverB.

I would like to be able to upload code from vsCode to serverB (preferably using sftp-extension). On my pc I am using socks-proxy (ssh -D 8080 serverA) to serverA so my IP-address changes to static which can be used to access serverB.

I can connect to serverB if I use `ssh -t serverA serverB`. But so far unable to find a way to easily upload code from vsCode to serverB, like I would if serverB would have no IP-restriction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the above scenario, I would try the following...

1. SSH onto those servers, install and use git to manage your code (this is just good practice).
2. Follow this article: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh

I have personally never used this extension but I have seen others use it with success.

I would highly recommend you that you don't work directly on the server unless you have to, keep your code on a remote git server and come up with a standard(eventually automated) way of deploying your PROD ready code.

Comment: That would be better practice. Currently using git locally and uploading changes to servers(prod and dev) using upload-on-save, since I am solo developer this have worked for years. Definitely option to start using git on servers.